# UITableView contentSize doesn't update in ios7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uiview, scrollview

I have a UITableViewController which loads some cells normally using the datasource delegate methods.

In ios8 everything works fine, but in ios7 the contentsize height doesnt seem to get the right height for the cells.

It adds the cells correctly which goes off-screen in the bottom, and when I want to scroll down it doesnt scroll, it just starts the bounce animation like you were at the bottom. When I drag I can see the cells below the bottom of the screen but when I release it bounce back.

I think its just some property im missing but I cant seem to find which one.

Im not configuring the table view at all, I just use the datasource to add the cells to it.

**EDIT**

I am using autolayout.

When I print out the contentsize it prints out CGSizeZero

```
var BookingInfo:[[String:AnyObject]]? { didSet { self.tableView.reloadData() } }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return BookingInfo == nil ? 0 : BookingInfo!.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let bookingInfo = BookingInfo![indexPath.row]
    let id = (bookingInfo["id"] as Int).toString()

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(id) as? ListCell
    if cell == nil { cell = ListCell(bookingInfo: bookingInfo, reuseID: id) }
    return cell!
}
```

BookingInfo is set in a prepareSegue function in another view before this one.

ListCell is a custom cell that loads a map using coordinates inside BookingInfo.

Im changing the cell ID for quick access when sorting so the map doesn't have to reload.

**EDIT 2**

Im using MapBox

```
class ListCell:UITableViewCell, RMMapViewDelegate {
    var BookingInfo:[String:AnyObject]!
    var mapView:RMStaticMapView!



    func mapView(mapView: RMMapView!, layerForAnnotation annotation: RMAnnotation!) -> RMMapLayer! {
        let marker = RMMarker(UIImage: UIImage(named: "MapPin.png")!.scaledImage(0.66))
        marker.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        annotation.layer = marker
        marker.canShowCallout = false

        return marker
    }

    func setup(frame: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor = nil

        let mapFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.height, height: frame.height)
        if mapView == nil {
        self.mapView = RMStaticMapView(frame: mapFrame, mapID: "an ID")

            if self.mapView != nil {
                self.mapView!.delegate = self
                self.mapView!.showLogoBug = false

                self.mapView!.setZoom(11, atCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.BookingInfo["lat"] as String).toDouble(), longitude: (self.BookingInfo["lon"] as String).toDouble()), animated: false)
                self.mapView!.addAnnotation(RMAnnotation(mapView: self.mapView, coordinate: self.mapView!.centerCoordinate, andTitle: ""))
                self.contentView.addSubview(self.mapView!)
            }
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        gcd.async(.Main) {
            self.setup(self.bounds)
        }

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    convenience init(bookingInfo: [String:AnyObject], reuseID: String) {
        self.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        self.BookingInfo = bookingInfo
    }
}
```

There is more in this class but they dont have anything to do with the map, they are just simple UILabels, removed them in question so it woudnt get too long.

**EDIT AFTER @ROB's ANSWER**

I added constraints but still contentSize becomes {0, 0}

```
// In viewDidLoad
self.tableView.rowHeight = 100   

// In ListCell.setup:
self.mapView = RMStaticMapView(frame: mapFrame, mapID: "an ID")
self.mapView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)    
self.contentView.addSubview(self.mapView!)

var arr = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[mapView]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["mapView":self.mapView])
arr += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[mapView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["mapView":self.mapView])
self.contentView.addConstraints(arr)

let constraintRatio = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mapView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.mapView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.mapView.addConstraint(constraintRatio)
```

Comment: @Rob It is a UITableViewController so the tableview will have its frame over the whole screen.

Comment: Thing is, I dont think it has something with MY code to do, I think its an ios7 behavior that messes things up.

Comment: I removed the map and then it worked fine... Its really weird and it only messes up in ios7. Ill update how I add the map to the ListCell.

Comment: @Rob If I remove the line where I add the map to contentView it works as its suppose to... I added it inside a disptach_after and after 5 sec it adds the map and as soon it added the tableView contentSize becomes CGSizeZero... Im so confused right now and have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the hard coded frame with constraints tied to the map view's super view (i.e. the `contentView`). Unrelated, but your process of using unique identifiers for each cell would probably be best handled using reusable cells, but then, when the map view is done rendering, use `MKMapSnapshotter` to make a snapshot of the image, cache that snapshot, and if you scroll back, show that, not the map view. Use map views for initial rendering of maps, but if the map doesn't change from that point on, then use snapshot.

Comment: I don't know what to say, as I cannot reproduce that behavior. Perhaps you can create the simplest possible project that reproduces this behavior, upload it somewhere, and we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you appear to be setting the frame of the map view to be the same as the bounds of the cell. I would, instead, define constraints for the map view that does the same basic thing:

```
let mapView = MKMapView()
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false
mapView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
contentView.addSubview(mapView)

let views = ["mapView" : mapView]
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[mapView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[mapView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

When I configured that (plus set the `rowHeight` of the tableView), it appeared fine in both iOS 7 and iOS 8.

If you have variable or dynamic cell heights, then the process is a little different. iOS 8 handles this sort of stuff more gracefully than iOS 7 does.

Comment: Im setting the map size to cellHeight, cellHeight, so I'll add some more constraints and Ill see if it works.